# Start an app minimized in c#

Tags: c#, trayicon, minimized

I'm trying to have an app start minimized in c# but "windowstate" library isn't available as I have selected to build "Blank app" in c# + I cant find the notifyIcon tool in the toolbox. I tried to find that as I read some solutions including it.

this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal

Isn't recognized as a command, as suggested in a possibility duplicate post, I've checked that and it does not match my case. I am not using Windows forms so this won't work anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start WinForm app minimized to tray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray)

Comment: You haven't said what framework you are using, WPF or WinForms, but this question has been asked and answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453998/c-sharp-run-application-minimized-at-windows-startup) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1730731/how-to-start-winform-app-minimized-to-tray), among other places, depending on what you're after specifically